# How do I find text between brackets while including the bracket using regex tokenization

Tags: python, regex, python-3.3

How do I extract the text inside the brackets using regex?
For example if I have

**string = 'This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] (ascd asdfas -were)'**

I want output to be

**[asdf-wer-a2-asdf], (ascd asdfas -were)**

I have looked everywhere for this and haven't been able to solve this problem. 
If anyone can help me that would be great

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried regex grouping (aka submatching)? The important point is that you have to **escape** your brackets if you want to match a literal bracket.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what do you mean by escaping? I was able to get the inner portion of the bracket but wasn't able to get the brackets. I am new to python so any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i edited my post i would appreciate if you check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below regex pattern. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/zD1pQ3/3) is an example

`\[[^\)]*\]|\([^)]*\)`

Comment: I think there one problem with that line. The problem I am seeing is if there is  **string = 'This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] (ascd asdfas -were)  test test test (testing test)'**. You get not only text inside bracket but also text inbetween to brackets. Here we will get '[asdf -wer -a2 asdf] ','(ascd asdfas -were)  test test test (testing test)'

Comment: you are right i didnt think about that but now i edited the example and pattern please try that one

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works for () but it doesn't work for [] for example if it has [] followed by [] it selectes everything between those brackets. I will try to work on it. as you already fixed (). Thank you once again

Comment: \[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\) try this one my bad

Answer (score 2):

```
st = 'This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] (ascd asdfas -were)'


import re

mo = re.search(r'(\[.+\])\s*(\(.+\))',st)

print(mo.groups(2)[0],mo.groups(2)[1])

[asdf -wer -a2 asdf] (ascd asdfas -were)
```

Answer (score 1):

> http://ideone.com/DmpYH1

This might not be the best solution, but is very concise. You specify to find the text between delimiters. I am supplying the start `[` and end `]` and then finally `(` and `)` for the curly ones.

```
s = 'This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] (ascd asdfas -were)'
print (s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")])
print (s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")])
```

Edit: If you want [] and (), simply do this:

```
print (s[s.find("["):s.find("]")+1])
print (s[s.find("("):s.find(")")+1])
```

Returns:

**[asdf -wer -a2 asdf]
(ascd asdfas -were)**

Comment: This also prints the text inside the bracket but doesn't print the bracket. I was able to get the text inside but can't get the brackets in that results. Is there no way to get the bracket as the part of output?